# SKScene autolayout adjust to iPhone and iPad

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, autolayout

I have created a app using SprikeKit and SKScene, the app runs perfectly on all iPhone simulators however with the iPad simulator, the top is cropped. Is there any settings to have this as an auto layout?

See image attached for GameScene.sks settings

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEbsa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No, SpriteKit does not behave the same as UIKit.  It is designed for game development, so an "auto layout" feature is something that would be considered a very low priority to implement since not many games would utilize it outside of an overlay.  If you want to make your game appear the same vertically on all devices,  then make your scene size a 3:4 aspect ratio.  This would mean that cropping will happen on the sides of iPhones.
You could fill in the extra space on the sides with eye candy like bushes so your iPad and iPhone will play the same, but iPad users would just see more.